# Questions not appearing in network profile

Tags: bug, profile-page

The **[network profile for a user](http://stackexchange.com/users/3604946/joel-mone?tab=accounts)** shows no questions ever asked. However, he did ask a question two months ago, as his **[dba.se profile](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/30712/joel-mone)** shows.

Could this be a bug?

The question was migrated from SO - maybe that is relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Seems perhaps that the dba.se data is cached/refreshed at a lower rate than we might expect (and whether that is different from other sites, I'm not sure).

For example, on [my network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/24165/aaron-bertrand?tab=accounts), it says that I have **868** answers on dba.se, yet on my [dba.se profile](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand), it says I have **897**. Based on my answer history, I probably had 868 about two months ago (but I didn't count all of my answers individually to see exactly when - it's also not clear if it should include deleted answers, as I definitely have at least one of those in the same time frame).